# on screen joystick controller math?

Tags: math, lua

I want to make something like in this video..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Em4Qa09-y90
but my problem is.. when i move my mouse out of the yellow circle.. the red controller on the video will completely stop moving, i want the controller still facing to my mouse position even when my mouse is out of the yellow circle..

```
    cx = 250
    cy = 250
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    curx = 0
    cury = 0
    dir = 0
    lg = graphics
    lm = mouse
end

function update()
    a = cx
    b = cy
    c = math.sqrt(math.pow(250 - lm.getX(), 2) + math.pow(lm.getY() - 250, 2))
    dir = math.atan2(250 - cx, cy - 250)

    if c < 200 then
        cx = lm.getX()
        cy = lm.getY()
    end
end

function draw()
    lg.setColor(0,0,0, 127.5)
    lg.circle("fill", cx, cy, 50)
    lg.print(c)
end
```

the screen width and height is 250 
`lm.getX()` and `lm.getY()` is to get the x and y position of the mouse
`sqrt` = square root
`pow` = power

Comment: Consider reformatting question text to make code readable, consider verifying that the code is valid lua code, consider mentioning the framework you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
if c < 200 then
    cx = lm.getX()
    cy = lm.getY()
end
```

with

```
local k = c > 200 and 200 / c or 1
cx = (lm.getX() - 250) * k + 250
cy = (lm.getY() - 250) * k + 250
```